# Destroy ajax loaded page and hide div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I'm using `.on()` with jQuery to show a div, and `.load()` to load in a particular div from a web page on my server.

How do I then close this div when I click off the div, and destroy it in the DOM so that it doesn't get loaded in multiple times?

It's a footer element, which can be shown / hidden on clicking a link in the footer.

I tried it with .off():

```
           if ($(window).width() > 500) {
            //
            $('.marketSelector',this.$element).on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var testMarketSelector = $('.testMarketSelector');
                testMarketSelector.css({
                    'display': 'block'
                });
                testMarketSelector.load( "/frontend/MarketSelector.html .MarketSelector" );
                testMarketSelector.off("click", function(){
                    testMarketSelector.css({
                        'display': 'none'
                    });
                });
            });
        }
```

I also tried .one():

```
        if ($(window).width() > 500) {
            //
            $('.marketSelector',this.$element).one('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var testMarketSelector = $('.testMarketSelector');
                testMarketSelector.css({
                    'display': 'block'
                });
                testMarketSelector.load( "/frontend/MarketSelector.html .MarketSelector" );
            });
        }
```

Comment: You can use `this.$element.off("click")` inside of the click event, or use `$('.marketSelector', this.$element).one('click', ...`

Answer (score 0):

Change your event to this:

```
$('.marketSelector', this.$element).one('click', function (e) { ... });
```

To destroy the div, as soon as you click outside the element, you can use a plugin, like outerclick or add a new event to the body.

Append this event listener when you open the Dialog:

```
var $marketingDialog = this.$element;
$("body").on("click.outer",function(event){ 
 // User did not clicked inside of the dialog
 if(!$marketingDialog.parents($(event.target)).length ){
    $marketingDialog.fadeOut();
    $marketingDialog.remove();
    $("body").off("click.outer"); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nico, I've tried that - as well as using .off() but it doesn't do anything for me? I'm going to update my question above.

Comment: Do you need to know how to destroy your element or do you wanted to know how to just call it once?

Comment: Just updated my question with more information. I need to be able to open / close this div (toggle view) when click a link.

Comment: I've cleaned up my answer. I can not test this right now. But i think it should work

Comment: Thank you Nico O, I think I understand, but I'm getting an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'parents' of undefined`

I added your code in the .load function call back.

Comment: $marketingDialog have not been defined.It need to point at the jQuery instance of your dialog.

Answer (score 0):

`testMarketSelector.load( ...);` API has success handler; call `testMarketSelector.off("click", ...)` in the success handler of `load()`. Also IIRC, there are issues if `load()` API call itself loads jquery as part of loading page (it seems jquery from page that loads in DIV overrides parent page jquery).

Comment: Thanks @rt2800, but that didn't work for me, what did I do wrong?
`testMarketSelector.load( "/frontend/MarketSelector.html .MarketSelector", function(){
                        testMarketSelector.off("click", function(){
                            testMarketSelector.css({
                                'display': 'none'
                            });
                        });
                    } );
                });
            }`